# How to replace adapter list of data without refreshing the recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

i have recyclerView in my fragment and i want to change the list of data in the recyclerView adapter without refreshing the recyclerView
i am using this two functions like that

mAdapter.clearList()
mAdapter.addItems(newList)

but there is a quick refresh because of clearList() function
anyone have better function to use

```
fun addItems(items: List<T>) {
        val myList = adapterItems()
        var count = myList.size
        // Remove loading indicator dummy item
        if (count > 0 && hasMore()) {
            count--
            myList.removeAt(count)
            notifyItemRemoved(count)
        }
        // Insert extra data
        myList.addAll(items)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(count, items.size)
    } 

 fun clearList() {
        val myList = adapterItems()
        val count = myList.size
        myList.clear()
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, count)
    }
```

Comment: Are you using DiffUtil for items in recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `setItems` function that clears and then adds *before* notifying the `RecyclerView` with `notifyDataSetChanged()` - I'm not sure if that would matter though, I feel like it should all be resolved before you get a layout pass and the screen updates. A glitch you can see feels like one thing happens and then another later - I'm not sure how it's all handled internally though, if these things are queued up or not. Worth a try!

Another thing you could try is using `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `clearList()` instead of `notifyItemRangeRemoved`. Since you're throwing out *everything* it makes more sense to just use the "everything has changed" notify call. I'm not sure if using a *rangeRemoved* call followed by a *rangeInserted* one might cause problems - it *shouldn't*, but depending on how it's resolved, there could be some quirks.

The other thing to check is that you're definitely only updating your adapter once - if whatever's causing that update fires twice in a short space of time, you could see it glitch